# Why does my coffee machine trip the electrical circuit during or shortly after brewing?

Tags: coffee-machines, troubleshooting

My Delonghi Magnifica ESAM 4200.s trips the electrical circuit.  When I reset the trip switch it continues it’s process. This happens every time whichever plug socket I use, even in a different house. No error lights are displayed.

Comment: Are you talking about a GFCI circuit like you find in kitchens (with a TEST button and a RESET button), or are you talking about a circuit breaker?

Comment: How many this are there in the circuit at one time?

Comment: Also, what switch are you taking about? Is it a circuit breaker or a switch inside the machine? If it's a switch inside the machine, can you post a picture of said switch? I ask because espresso machines have a high temp limit switch that will disable the boiler in case temperatures get too hot, and if that's what's tripping, it probably doesn't have anything to do with electricity.

Answer (score 2):

If you have observed the problem *on different outlets* and even *in different houses*, the only *common* factor is the machine itself. The exact cause can’t be assessed via the Internet and unless you are experienced with repairing electrical machinery, I would **strongly discourage** you to start experimenting blindly. The missing error lights are not an indicator here, they would only signal a problem that an otherwise functional machine can detect via the built-in self-checks. Tripping a circuit breaker is in a different league of defect.

For your own safety: **Please stop using the machine** (faulty electric alone is bad enough, add water to the mix and it gets really dangerous), even if it seems to “work”, sort of. Contact a qualified service technician or the seller/manufacturer (especially if it’s still under warranty) and have them assess the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Upon second thoughts, the boiler may not be the culprit here, looks like the resistance is working properly otherwise it would trip whenever it's heating up the water. Instead you tell me that it trips when you start making coffee making the pump a possible culprit instead. The first thing i would do is unplug the machine and open the back panel, look for water leaks that could be causing a short circuit in the high voltage parts, that's the high-voltage circuit board, pump, boiler and solenoid valves.
If no obvious water leaks are detected you may need to take it to an authorized repair center for diagnosis and repair.

**STOP USING THE MACHINE RIGHT NOW**

**DO NOT ATTEMPT ANY REPAIRS BY YOURSELF UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.**